# Searching in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search

Can someone explain me step by step procedure for enabling searching in SharePoint 2013?

Whenever I try to search anything in search box it displays "Nothing here matches your search"

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502597(v=office.15).aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582314(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Robert is it necessary to create new search service application?cant we use default ?

Comment: Well if you already have one, that is up and running, skip that step

Comment: Are you using Foundation or Server?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following link to configure search in Sharepoint 2013

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12714.sharepoint-2013-quickshoot-to-the-search-services-application.aspx